# Why is my ApplicationInsights.config file not being included in the MSBuild build and publish

Tags: azure-application-insights

Why is my ApplicationInsights.config file not being included in the build package when I build on the server. I am using Azure DevOps as the build server and I am using a standard Visual Studio build task. This is the MSBuild arguments

/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\" /p:SkipPostSharp=True /p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=False

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code base has been inherited from another team. It turns out that they modified the project file to add a new MSBuild Targets file. These additional tasks were responsible for ensuring the config file was not added in to the output.

Answer (score 2):

This could be happening due to an incorrect App Publish profile. Your application's local Publish profile in VS should ideally look like this:

- [CustomProfile.pubcxml.user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eb7hU.png) file

This should include:

```
 <File Include="ApplicationInsights.config">
   <publishTime>11/06/2018 12:27:58</publishTime>
 </File>
```

- [*ProjectName*.csproj file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sD0GD.png)

Unload your project (Right click on Project Name -> Unload Project) and edit the project's .csproj file (Right click on Project Name -> Edit .csproj)

```
 <Content Include="ApplicationInsights.config">
   <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
 </Content>
```

- [Publish Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsiGg.png)

The above mentioned settings would ensure that the ApplicationInsights.config file is included as part of your Publish artifacts, which would look as shown in the attached screenshot.

If this is not what you see, please try creating a new Publish profile afresh and tweak it to get the expected configuration. Post verifying this, I did try to publish the same using the MSBuild task in Azure DevOps and was able to see ApplicationInsights.config as part of the output build artifacts, supplying the same parameters that you mentioned in the question above:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\" /p:SkipPostSharp=True /p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=False
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, ApplicationInsights.config file is set to "Copy Never" in the properties / project file. Changing this to "Copy if Newer" or "Copy Always" should do the trick.

Comment: It was set to "Copy if Newer" but I set it to "Copy Always" and that had no effect

Comment: I see (it's known that Nuget installation of some AI SDK packages does not set "Copy if Newer"). Is it a transitive dependency (i.e. AI is added to a library and that library is referenced by the web project)? Adding explicitly into the web project may help in that case. I assume it works locally in VS in your case, so it may have to do with the artifactsstagindirectory, e.g. ApplicationInsights.config is not places there while locally it's available for the packaging right in the app folder.

Comment: I followed the instructions on how to add AI here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net The file is in the root of the site it does work locally to send messages to AI, but the publishing does not work. if I create a publish profile that publishes to a local file system then the file is not in the package.